# Unable to run Nosetests on classes or functions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm, nose

I am using pycharm and are trying to run individual tests. My "run all tests works (used py.test), but I want to run specific tests. When I try to run the Nosetest i get this error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

My wsgi.py looks like this:

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "v3.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: have you tried running specific tests using py.test?  `py.test [module_filepath]::[name_of_test]`(Source: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: you mean in the terminal?  like python manage.py py.test [[module_filepath] : : [name_of_test]

Comment: Your wsgi file is irrelevant to running tests. But you at least need to show how you've configured your tests, and the command you use to run them.

Comment: @Marviel Your example works for specific modules and even the classes of the test.
python -m pytest test_services.py::TestUpgradeToInvoice

But is it also possible to test only functions too?

Comment: @AdamaCamara yeah, I run specific functions all the time! If TestUpgradeToInvoice is a class, then you just do it like this, as per the link I posted previously: `pytest test_mod.py::TestClass::test_method`

Comment: you are a lifesaver!!!

Comment: @Marviel How do i notify your answer as the answer?

Comment: @AdamaCamara I'll reformat it as an answer and post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried running specific tests using py.test?** e.g. on the command line:

`py.test [module_filepath]::[name_of_test]`

In your case, it looks like you might be trying to run a function inside a class, which would look like:
`py.test test_mod.py::TestClass::test_method`

*(Source: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html )*

*(reformatted from comments so answer can be accepted)*